# Correct C++ syntax in Qt "connect"?

Tags: c++

I am learning how to use `connect` in Qt.
I have an idea how it works when connecting widgets in current object.

My problem is - I do not fully understand C++ syntax when connecting two objects.

My current learning test task is to pass `item` selected in `list` to `list_2` using C++ code - in current object. (I know how to implement that using QtDesigner - but I want to learn using code)

```
QListWidgetItem item;
connect(ui->list,
    &QListWidget::itemClicked(QListWidgetItem &item),
    ui->list_2,
    &QListWidget::addItem(&item));
```

The above code gives me two errors and I need help to IDENTIFY  what is wrong with my C++ syntax.

```
/media/f/QT/Qt/QT/qtconnectivity/examples/bluetooth/CAT_BT_18112020/device.cpp:127: error: expected primary-expression before '&' token
         &QListWidget::itemClicked(QListWidgetItem &item),

/media/f/QT/Qt/QT/qtconnectivity/examples/bluetooth/CAT_BT_18112020/device.cpp:129: error: cannot call member function 'void QListWidget::addItem(QListWidgetItem*)' without object
                 &QListWidget::addItem(&item));
                                        ^
```

Thank you

**I like to add / edit / clarify the post.**

It would be helpful to start with knowing the convention / symbols in this C++ `connect` code.

What are the piece parts `[=](){...}` of "lambda" syntax in English?

```
connect(action, &QAction::triggered, engine,
        [=]() { engine->processAction(action->text()); });
```

Perhaps help me by applying similar to my initial `connect` code.

Comment: Your syntax errors are basic C++ errors (nevermind illegal Qt).  Look here for some correct examples: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html.  SUGGESTION: Study the code that the designer emits.

Comment: You should learn to put your code parts in code blocks so that the question looks better. It will help you getting the answer since the reader don't have to spend too much effort

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for the connect statement should be

```
connect(list_widget_1,
        &QListWidget::itemClicked,
        list_widget_2,
        QOverload<QListWidgetItem*>::of(&QListWidget::addItem));
```

Because `addItem()` has 2 overloads, `QOverload` must be used

```
QListWidget::addItem(const QString &label)
QListWidget::addItem(QListWidgetItem *item)
```

But you don't want to do this, since the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#addItem) specifically said that:

> Warning: A QListWidgetItem can only be added to a QListWidget once. Adding the same QListWidgetItem multiple times to a QListWidget will result in undefined behavior.

Instead you should do something like this

```
connect(list_widget_1,
        &QListWidget::itemClicked,
        [list_widget_2](QListWidgetItem *item)
{
    list_widget_2->addItem(item->clone());
});
```

Explanation for the lambda part:

- Inside the square brackets is the capturing part. In the following body of the lambda, I need to use `list_widget_2`, so I need to capture it.
- Inside the parentheses is the place for the parameters. This part is like normal functions. Since `itemClicked()` passes a `QListWidgetItem *`, I will take it as parameter for the lambda.
- Inside the curly braces is the lambda body. This part is like normal functions.

More information on lambda in the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)

Comment: If you find the answer helpful, please consider upvoting and marking it correct.